# data visualisation - ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualise my data using ggplot. I have two groups whose evolution I'd like to represent using different types of lines. One would be "dotdashed" and the other "solid".

For now, I have written this code.

```
ggplot(data_zscores, aes(x = cohort, y = zscore, group = group))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "grey")+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean",
               geom = "point",
               size = 1)+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", 
               geom = "line",
               size = 0.3,
               aes(group=interaction(group)))+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean",
               geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.15,
               fun.max = function(y) mean(y) + se(y), 
               fun.min = function(y) mean(y) -se(y),
               aes(group=interaction(group,cohort)))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotdash", "solid"))+
  facet_wrap(. ~ condition)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())+
  ylab("mean z-accuracy")+
  xlab("cohort")+
  ggtitle('Difference in accuracy z-score 
          between Y1 and Y3 for each group and condition')
```

Everything works except that both lines are both "solid". How shall I do to obtain the result I'm looking for?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi gaelle. Would you be able to share some of the data? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(data_zscores)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data_zscores, 20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the line type inside your `aes()` function where you specify the group aesthetic. You need to map the linetype aesthetic to your group variable. The linetype should be specified in the `aes()` function within the `geom_line` or `stat_summary` call not the `ggplot` function call.

```
ggplot(data_zscores, aes(x = cohort, y = zscore))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "grey")+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean",
               geom = "point",
               size = 1)+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", 
               geom = "line",
               size = 0.3,
               aes(group=interaction(group), linetype=group))+
  stat_summary(fun = "mean",
               geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.15,
               fun.max = function(y) mean(y) + se(y), 
               fun.min = function(y) mean(y) -se(y),
               aes(group=interaction(group,cohort)))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotdash", "solid"))+
  facet_wrap(. ~ condition)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())+
  ylab("mean z-accuracy")+
  xlab("cohort")+
  ggtitle('Difference in accuracy z-score 
          between Y1 and Y3 for each group and condition')
```

In the `aes()` function within the `stat_summary` call for the line geometry, I have added `linetype=group`. This tells `ggplot` to use different line types for different groups. The `scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotdash", "solid"))` line then specifies what these line types should look like.

Please make sure that the `group` variable is a factor and its levels align with the specified line types in the `scale_linetype_manual` function. If there are more than two groups, you need to add more `linetypes` to the `scale_linetype_manual` function. If the group variable is not a factor, you can convert it to a factor using the `factor()` function.

Comment: that's absolutely perfect. Thank you!